# Just seen a stylesheet called style.css?v=30

Tags: html, css

Looking at the web designer website and viewing their source code they have a link to their css file like this:

How do they put the style.css?v=30 the query after the style sheet and make it go to the right file or have they actually named that file style.css?v=30.

Comment: you can do that statically every time you update the css or you can use PHP in any number of ways to write it out. It's to force browser to overwrite cache if a change is made. Part of a cache buster method. v=<?php echo time(); ?> for example

Comment: Whats the main advantage of doing this? Also I apologies for the duplicate I couldn't find that question.

Answer (score 1):

actually `filename.ext?v=something` is a way to control caching process of browser. whenever u open any webpage, browser saves a copy of it and we call it cache. So next time when u open that page again, browser doesn't actually download the whole page, it just use its cached copy to view it. And it looks that your site opens up faster than first time. 
Now suppose you are using a css files named `style.css`, when someone open your webpage first time, his browser will download the `style.css` and make a cached copy of it. now let next time you opened that webpage again and before that developer actually changed the `style.css` but since your browser doesn't know it, it will just show the same cached copy and you can't see the new file.
So preventing this thing, developer add a string in file name named version detail like `style.css?v=30`, now when you browser read it, it will be cached with version value, but next time when you open that same page again, and let developer has changed `style.css` , so he will upload it with new version value let say `style.css?v=234`, now browser check and see that it is new value, browser will read it as new file, it will be downloaded and viewed in your viewport.


There are several method of preventing caching your files by browser, one of them is adding a random version string at the end, you can use random string generating function from php named `<?php echo uniqid(); ?>` from php or add any new value.
Other way is to define a rewrite rule in your .htaccess file if you are using apache server or by adding a expire header in your html head `<meta name="expires" content="tue, 01 Jun 2010">`. 
I really expect that you got it completely.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps they are using some directory-level configuration like a .htaccess file, to redirect style.css to a PHP file that generates CSS which in some way makes use of the query.

Comment: I doubt so. It is mostly for caching purposes.

Comment: That's true, @Terry . Probably.